# How can I make all html tags close in the same line with php

Tags: php, regex, dom, preg-replace, htmlpurifier

For example, if I have

```
<b>Line 1
Line 2</b>
```

I want to make it become

```
<b>Line 1</b>
<b>Line 2</b>
```

thanks.

Comment: what is the difference bw these two? when u run these on browser?

Comment: I need the HTML code to be converted to some other codes, which I need it to be in this format in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a simple way to go about this if you're using code, though it's generally frowned upon to use regex to parse / handle HTML or any markup language.

First of all, the pattern:

```
/<b>(.*?)<\/b>/s
```

What this will do, is capture everything (ungreedy) between `<b>` and the next `</b>`, including the tags.

The full match will be the entire string (to replace) and the captured group will be the text to replace it with (with a bit of modification in code).

The way to do this is to get all the matches, and then iterate each match (go from last to first), explode the captured group on `\n`, then wrap each string with `<b>` and `</b>` before imploding it back with `\n` again.

Replace the match with this resulting string. This will also handle the case where you have `<b>` and `</b>` on the same line already.

PHP example:

```
$string = <<<EOD
<b>Bold Text
Bold Text</b>
Normal Text
Normal Text
<b>Bold Text</b>
EOD;

preg_match_all("/<b>(.*?)<\/b>/s", $string, $matches, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
for ($match = count($matches[0]) - 1; $match >= 0; $match--) {
    $replace = implode("\n", array_map(function ($str) {
        return "<b>".$str."</br>";
    }, explode("\n", $matches[1][$match])));
    $string = str_replace($matches[0][$match], $replace, $string);
}

echo $string;
```

will output:

```
<b>Bold Text</b>
<b>Bold Text</b>
Normal Text
Normal Text
<b>Bold Text</b>
```

Comment: I can't seem to get it work, any idea why? thx https://rextester.com/live/YRBQ80020

Comment: @user2335065 yes you need to allow regex to match `\n` with `.` - you can do this by supplying the `/s` switch. I'll update my answer to reflect this.

Answer (score -1):

This solves the problem... not sure it's the best solution without knowing more specifics though.

```
<?php
$string = '<b>Bold Text
Bold Text</b>';

$lines = explode("\n", $string);

$output = implode('</b><b>', $lines);

echo $output;
```